# Fragment under the toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, toolbar

I never used the menu + fab in my projects before. So I made 3 tab fragments and all 3 shows listview but my fragments are going under the toolbar

Here is the code - fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="VEHICLES REQUESTED"
    android:textColor="#88bf40"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/vehicle_LV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using it or the first time with fab and menu navigation please let me know if I'm something wrong here.

MainActivity xml code - activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:backgroundTint="#303440"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Giving margin is one way but I doubt this is a right way of solving this. Anyone have any Idea what to do?

ScreenShot - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICC5w.jpg)

Comment: What's the problem ? i think i'm misunderstood

Comment: My listView is below my toolbar and I think the reason is it doesn't have any toolbar in it's view.

Comment: So your toolbar and tabs must be combined ?

Comment: yes they are? Is there any problem bcoz of that?

Comment: Did you check my answer ?

Comment: Yes but I get the answer it's because my theme was set no toolbar for that layout so I changed that to with toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for all other people who are looking answers for the same Question.

So the problem was with my theme it was default set to no action bar.
So I changed this to the theme with action bar.

Here is the code I added to my xml.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

and Here is the code which I added in my styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this attribute will help you

> layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf

usage:

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your `AppBarLayout`

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```